# portfolio image gallery with filters for years from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, image-gallery

I have a database table with columns subject, year and image link. somewhat like below.

```
subject     |    year   |  image_link
------------------------------------------------
ABC1        |    1988   |  img/image1.jpg
ABC2        |    1988   |  img/image2.jpg
ABC3        |    1992   |  img/image3.jpg
ABC4        |    1994   |  img/image4.jpg
ABC5        |    1994   |  img/image5.jpg
ABC6        |    1996   |  img/image6.jpg
ABC7        |    1998   |  img/image7.jpg
```

I want to display this data with filter by year.

Following code if with static image links.

How can I use it dynamically with data from mysql table ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
        <li><span class="filter active" data-filter=".app, .card, .icon, .logo, .web">All</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".app">App</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".card">Card</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".icon">Icon</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".logo">Logo</span></li>
        <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".web">Web</span></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="portfoliolist">

        <div class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">             
                <img src="img/logo/5.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="label">
                    <div class="label-text">
                        <a class="text-title">Bird Document</a>
                        <span class="text-category">Logo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-bg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              

        <div class="portfolio app" data-cat="app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">         
                <img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="label">
                    <div class="label-text">
                        <a class="text-title">Visual Infography</a>
                        <span class="text-category">APP</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-bg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div class="portfolio web" data-cat="web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">                     
                <img src="img/web/4.jpg" alt=""/>
                <div class="label">
                    <div class="label-text">
                        <a class="text-title">Sonor's Design</a>
                        <span class="text-category">Web design</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-bg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function () {
 var filterList = { 
    init: function () {     
        // MixItUp plugin
        // http://mixitup.io
        $('#portfoliolist').mixItUp({
            selectors: {
          target: '.portfolio',
          filter: '.filter' 
      },
      load: {
          filter: '.app' // show app tab on first load
        }     
        });                             

    }

  };

   // Run the show!
    filterList.init();

 });    
});
</script>
```

I tried it with static data (manually entering image links and other display text and it is working.

But I want to create filters by Year in database and then display respective images as yearwise.

How Can I make it working ?

I currently used following php code. but with that only filters with years buttons are seen. No images seen.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
        <li><span class="filter active" data-filter=".app, .all, .icon, .logo, .web">All</span></li>
       <?php
       $query = "select * from $performances_table group by year order by year asc";
       $result = $database->get_results($query);
         foreach($result as $data){     
            $year = $data['year'];
       ?>     
          <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".<?php echo $year;?>"><?php echo $year;?></span></li>   
      <?php } ?>  
   </ul>
```

with this code, Filters by years button links are being created properly. But I am stuck How to use image display part. In loop ( foreach above) is not working... (replacating  of filter...)

**What can be Code for image display part ?**

```
<div class="portfolio <?php echo $data['year'];?>" data-cat="<?php echo $data['year'];?>">
        <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
            <img src="img/<?php echo $data['image_link'];?>" alt="" />
            <div class="label">
                <div class="label-text">
                    <a class="text-title"><?php echo $data['subject'];?></a> 
                    <span class="text-category"><?php echo $data['year'];?></span>
                </div>
            <div class="label-bg"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be <img src="<?php echo $data['image_link'];?>" alt="" />

Comment: basically it is typo mistake... it is image_link. But problem is image display part is out of foreach statement... so how can I show image section dynamically...

Comment: Simply repeat the foreach($result as $data){  and put your code between the brackets-

Comment: `select * from $performances_table group by year order by year asc` is not a valid query; it returns an indeterminate result. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry What should be query then for various and multiple records in database.. ?

Comment: It all depends what you want

Answer (score -1):

You can generate both parts in loop and assign in variables and after it you can use both variables on their respectively sections.

```
<?php
$thumbnail = $img_gallry = '';
$query = "select * from $performances_table group by year order by year asc";
$result = $database->get_results($query);
foreach($result as $data){
$year = $data['year'];
$thumbnail .= '<li><span class="filter" data-filter=".'.$year.'">'.$year.'</span></li>';
$img_gallry .= '<div class="portfolio '.$year.'" data-cat="'.$year.'"><div class="portfolio-wrapper"><img src="img/'.$data['image_link'].'" alt="" /><div class="label"><div class="label-text"><a class="text-title">'.$data['subject'].'</a><span class="text-category">'.$data['year'].'</span></div><div class="label-bg"> </div></div></div></div>";
?>
<?php } ?>
<div class="container">
<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
<li><span class="filter active" data-filter=".app, .all, .icon, .logo, .web">All</span></li>
<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: The query is still invalid though, which makes a nonsense of the rest of the code.

Comment: @darsan did you check?